# (Beginner) Binary conversion program Issue

Tags: binary, flowchart

I am a beginner to development and have made a flowchart in RAPTOR which can be run.
The program converts an 8-bit binary value to decimal, however whenever it's run it always outputs 0 as the final answer.

The issue I think is the if statement circled in Red which always seems to evaluate to 0 for some reason.

[image: My Flowchart in Raptor of Binary Conversion program]

Comment: I am not sure how RAPTOR interprets strings, but you should probably be looking to match "1" or '1' (the ASCII character) and not 1 (the integer).

Comment: Yes, Raptor does seem to adapt some non standard rules e.g. 0 can't be used in arrays. Putting the number 1 as a string character ( in "" marks) produces the error "Can't compare these values: NUMBER_KIND STRING_KIND"

Comment: ...*Installs Raptor*... Also, `GET strBin[8]` does not return a string with 8 characters, it returns an array of 8 strings, the 8th index of which is filled with the input. Perhaps you should consider using a different program.

Comment: Yes, think the latter point would be wise. Thank you Rotem, I would upvote if I could!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by summary of the conversation by @Jtaylor-Pentacle, @Rotem.

The [RAPTOR Flowchart based programming](http://raptor.martincarlisle.com/) seems to have some unique syntax and is primarily used as a training tool in some Universities. 
If you are looking to learn programming, the suggestion is to move away from Raptor and dive in and find a language to learn.